# Google Feed API max-results not displaying more than 250 entries

Tags: json, google-feed-api

I am using Google Feed API to read the RSS Feeds and display them on my page.

The feed I am using consist of about 284 (approx) entries as of now, and is continuously increasing. But I am able to view only 250 top entries.

Can anyone please help me to increase this number? I tried setting the `.setNumEntries(1000)` still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If I recall correctly, 250 has been the max since the API was started" from: [How to get More than 250 Entries using Google Feeds API](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Google-AJAX-Search-API/YHjRrjQImWg)

Comment: True and the future of Google Feeds API is uncertain (well not sure about Yahoo pipes, either)